# SQL to search duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table for animals like

- Lion
- Tiger
- Elephant
- Jaguar
- List item
- Cheetah
- Puma
- Rhino

I want to insert new animals in this table and I am t reading the animal names from a CSV file.

Suppose I got following names in the file

Lion,Tiger,Jaguar

as these animals are already in "Animals" table, What should be a single SQL query that will determine if the animals are already exist in the table.

**Revision 1**

***I want a query that will give me the list of animals that are already in table. I donot want a query to insert that animal.
I just want duplicate animals***

Comment: if you're using SQL Server 2008, check out the MERGE statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just check if a Lion is already in the table:

```
select count(*) from animals where name = 'Lion'
```

You can do the check and the insert in one query with a `where` clause:

```
insert into animals (name) 
select  'Lion'
where not exists 
        (
        select * from animals where name = 'Lion'
        )
```

In reply to your comment, to select a sub-list of animals:

```
select name from animals where name in ('Lion', 'Tiger', 'Jaguar')
```

This would return up to 3 rows for each animal that already exists.

Comment: can I have a single query where I can pass multiple parameters at once and just get the list of the animals that are already in table.

I do not want query to add the animals .

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(your_animal_column) FROM tblAnimals WHERE your_animal_column = ?;

The question marks get filled by your csv values.
If this statement returns more than 0 there the value already exists

Answer (score 0):

If your incoming file is already in a normalized column format, instead of comma separated like you have displayed, it should be easy.  Create a temp table for the insert, then something like..

```
insert into YourLiveTable ( animalname ) 
   select Tmp.animalname
      from YourTempInsertTable Tmp
      where Tmp.animalname not in 
               ( select Live.animalname  
                    from YourLiveTable Live )
```

To match your revised request... just use the select portion and change "NOT IN" to "IN"

```
   select Tmp.animalname
      from YourTempInsertTable Tmp
      where Tmp.animalname IN 
               ( select Live.animalname  
                    from YourLiveTable Live )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT ANIMAL_NAME, COUNT(*)
FROM ANIMALS
GROUP BY ANIMAL_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This should give you all the duplicate entries

Comment: That would find animals that are already duplicated in the table.  If I understand the question correctly, the OP would like to prevent duplicates while importing a CSV file

Comment: The revised question says "I just want duplicate animals"